# Wireless driver installation issues on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, apt, broadcom

My wireless card just stopped working from one update to the next. Here is the update log from `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:46
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.80-1.1ubuntu1, 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:47

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.1, 7.0.0-4ubuntu0.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:51

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:55

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:54:59
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:00

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:03
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2), libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2), libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:03

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:06
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python-apt-common:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:07

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:10
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:10

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:13
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libwavpack1:amd64 (5.2.0-1, 5.2.0-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:13

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libopenjp2-7:amd64 (2.3.1-1ubuntu4, 2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:16

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: p11-kit:amd64 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1), p11-kit-modules:amd64 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1), libp11-kit0:amd64 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:21

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:55:24
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-38-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.8.0-38-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-38:amd64 (5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.8.0-38-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.61, 5.8.0.38.43~20.04.23), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.61, 5.8.0.38.43~20.04.23), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.61, 5.8.0.38.43~20.04.23)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:05

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:08
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, 5.4.0-62.70)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:08

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:11
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:13

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:16

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libproxy-tools:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:20

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:22
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:28

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:31
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: tzdata:amd64 (2020d-0ubuntu0.20.04, 2020f-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:32

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:34
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xdg-utils:amd64 (1.1.3-2ubuntu1.20.04.1, 1.1.3-2ubuntu1.20.04.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:35

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:38
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: tar:amd64 (1.30+dfsg-7, 1.30+dfsg-7ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:40

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-apt:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:43

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:46
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:56:47

Start-Date: 2021-01-20  09:58:26
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.186'
Install: libllvm11:amd64 (1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: netplan.io:amd64 (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3, 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 (3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.7+git20201123-0.20.04.1), libegl1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libgl1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libasound2-data:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3), lsof:amd64 (4.93.2+dfsg-1, 4.93.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgles2:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libmutter-6-0:amd64 (3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.7+git20201123-0.20.04.1), libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libgbm1:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mutter-common:amd64 (3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.7+git20201123-0.20.04.1), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libglx0:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), nautilus-sendto:amd64 (3.8.6-3, 3.8.6-3ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libasound2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3), libnetplan0:amd64 (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3, 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.6, 1.187.8), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libatopology2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3), mutter:amd64 (3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.7+git20201123-0.20.04.1), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglvnd0:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
Remove: linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-headers-5.4.0-56:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-20  09:59:23
```

The computer can still see the network card, as evidenced by `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85df]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

But I have issues installing the driver. When I installed 20.04 two months back, I ran `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` and one other command (I suspect it was `sudo modprobe wl`, but my notes are a bit fuzzy there), and then it worked.

Now, on the other hand, that's not enough. I suspect it's the new 5.8 kernel. I try to run `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` again, and it just tells me it's on the latest version. I `apt remove` it and then try to reinstall it, but then I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1 544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8 068 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 207709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-38-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more informati
on.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess retur
ned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I consult the log, and it says

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom for kernel 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
on. 20. jan. 21:40:51 +0100 2021
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c: In function ‘osl_reg_map’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:949:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ioremap_nocache’; did you mean ‘ioremap_cache’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  949 |  return (ioremap_nocache((unsigned long)pa, (unsigned long)size));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          ioremap_cache
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:949:10: warning: returning ‘int’ from a function with return type ‘void *’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  949 |  return (ioremap_nocache((unsigned long)pa, (unsigned long)size));
      |         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_attach’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:593:20: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ioremap_nocache’; did you mean ‘ioremap_cache’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  593 |  if ((wl->regsva = ioremap_nocache(dev->base_addr, PCI_BAR0_WINSZ)) == NULL) {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    ioremap_cache
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:593:18: warning: assignment to ‘void *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  593 |  if ((wl->regsva = ioremap_nocache(dev->base_addr, PCI_BAR0_WINSZ)) == NULL) {
      |                  ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_pci_probe’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:780:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  780 |  if ((val & 0x0000ff00) != 0)
      |  ^~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:782:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  782 |   bar1_size = pci_resource_len(pdev, 2);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:783:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  783 |   bar1_addr = (uchar *)ioremap_nocache(pci_resource_start(pdev, 2),
      |               ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:40:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_set_auth_type’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.h:52:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
   52 |  if (wl_dbg_level & WL_DBG_DBG) {   \
      |     ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:816:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘WL_DBG’
  816 |   WL_DBG(("network eap\n"));
      |   ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:817:2: note: here
  817 |  default:
      |  ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_reg_proc_entry’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3376:58: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create_data’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 3376 |  if ((wl->proc_entry = proc_create_data(tmp, 0644, NULL, &wl_fops, wl)) == NULL) {
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          const struct file_operations *
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:38:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:102:31: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct file_operations *’
  102 | extern struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic'
```

I don't know what to make of these logs. Does it look like anything that can be done, or am I doomed to wired connection until I can get a more compatible wireless card?

Comment: Good news! There *is* something that can be done. Please consult the duplicate.

Comment: @chili555 For some reason I didn't think to search for "bcmwl" or similar specific terms when looking for solutions; I was a lot more generic in my terms. Thanks a bunch!